# Part of the Wave Animation is Not Moving in Animation Render in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, displacement

I was animating wave using cloud texture displacement in Cycles Engine.

Everything looks fine in the wireframe view, all the wave is animated and moving for the whole length, however, when I [render my animation, part of the wave is not animated](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/19G7xFK1VZKd9LY897V8WKje2x0Vwt-jZ).

The part highlighted in "white" in the images is not moving, and the rest of the wave is moving for the whole length of the animation.[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome. Please add images that *show the problem* rather than only linking to tutorials and files. As your question is currently written, it depends on other users viewing a 15 minute video and downloading a file to completely understand your question. If you need to link to a video, please add the relevant timestamp to your question so that users know where in the video you are referencing.